# can i get my project source code from google developer console

Tags: google-developers-console

I was working on a project but due to some reason I lost the source code of my project . I was using google authentication for that project hence it is there on Google Developer Console . Is there any way I can get my code back from google developer console .

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Google Developer Console but, isn't it just a control panel to manage API credentials and similar stuff? Perhaps the question is missing context. What circumstances could have led to Google grabbing a copy of your source code?

Comment: _I was using google authentication for that project hence it is there on Google Developer Console_ how did you get this conclusion?